# Working with PHP global variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate my regular php build script into wordpress. I am stuck in a place where the function works perfectly before, but not in wordpress environment.

In the code below, I am getting blank array in my ajax request whereas I do have results inside myFunc (I have tested by putting wp_send_json inside).

Do I need to change anything to work with PHP globals in wordpress?

```
$final = array();
function myFunc(){
        global $wpdb;
        global $final;
        $sql = 'SELECT .......';
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ( $result as $row ) {
                $final[] = $row->pdate;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
myFunc();
wp_send_json($final);
```

Comment: Nope. This should work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah... `global` keyword seen... here live dragons! Is there _really_ no other way for this, except for using global variables? Especially generic names line `$final` carry the issue that you create a name collision with any other arbitrary part of code that by accident happens to use the same variable name...

Comment: actually I have to run a large SQL query (involving another dragon, joining 2 sub query) for last 15 years ... so rather than running that at once, I decided to run it 15 times .. and store in the global variable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following statements to get updated value from function.

```
  $arr = array();
   function myFunc($new_arr){
            global $wpdb;
            $sql = 'SELECT .......';
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
                foreach ( $result as $row ) {
                    $new_arr[] = $row->pdate;
                }

            }
           //It will return updated array if result having rows.Otherwise return empty array.
           return $new_arr;
    }
    $final = myFunc($arr);
    if(!empty($final))//if block will be execute if myFunc doesn't return empty array.
    {
       wp_send_json($final);
    }
```

Comment: You can add myFunc($arr) value with in the for loop according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

That should work but globals are nasty things to use and will often conflict I'd suggest just returning the array from the function.

e.g.

```
function myFunc(){
        global $wpdb;
        $final = array();
        $sql = 'SELECT .......';
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ( $result as $row ) {
                $final[] = $row->pdate;
            }
            return $final;
        }
        return false;
}

$myFuncReturn = myFunc();
if($myFuncReturn !== false){
   wp_send_json($myFuncReturn);
}
```

Comment: just call the last four lines 15 times in your loop. or you can adjust the myFunc and keep parsing it the array and apend to each each time. As your not passing the function any information for it's sql how is going to return different data each time thru the loop?